# Как сделать кнопку "Показать еще" для подгрузки контента?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Как сделать кнопку "Показать еще" для подгрузки контента внизу страницы с товарами под этими товарами, чтобы при нажатии на нее она пропадала и подгружались еще товары, и эта кнопка при наличии еще товаров опять появлялась внизу страницы?
Html:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($items as $val):?>
      <li class="item>{{$val->name}}</li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <button id="show_btn">Показать еще</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Js ajax

```
$("#show_btn").click(function(){
  .....
});
```

Comment: надо на сервер отправлять текущий размер загруженных данных и потом пропускать при выборке и потом получения ответ добавлять в разметке

Comment: А как пропускать эти данные при выборке? Мы же не знаем сколько раз нажимали эту кнопку

Comment: Передавать значит надо на сервер текущее число выведенных товаров.

Comment: например над подгрузить 20 штук   table.skip(40).take(20) то есть пропускам 40 первых потомучто ни уже у нас на странице и выбраем после него 20 следубющих не знаю аналогов в php

Comment: А что же насчет защиты?

Comment: какой защиты??? отчего

Comment: Происходит оправка запроса на сервер при каждом нажатии. Должны же быть какие-то меры защиты от ботов, нажимающих эту кнопку?

Comment: А расскажите зачем это могло бы понадобиться ботам и что страшного если они будут это делать?

Comment: перегрузка сервера запросами